# Change the alpha of recyclerview item with beacon detection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, ibeacon, android-viewholder

In a `Fragment` I have a list of items construct with `RecyclerView` (adapter and viewholder).
Each item of the list is linked with a estimote beacon.
So i want to highlight the item view (setAlpha or add a imageView) when the beacon is detected.

The beacon detection is in the fragment file :

```
beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);   
                    replaceIconBeaconCard(nearestBeacon);                     
                    Log.d("Airport", "Nearest places: " + nearestBeacon);
                }
            }
        });
```

Actually, I display a beacon icon on the item view. But the purpose is to highlight the detected item and put a alpha on the others items.

```
private void replaceIconBeaconCard(Beacon beacon){
        for(SItem item: items) {
            if (!item.getMajor().equals("")) {
                int i = item.getId().intValue();
                SCard card = listCards.get(i-1);
                if (Integer.parseInt(item.getMajor()) == beacon.getMajor()) {
                    rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(i);                    
                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("beacon_ice", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
                    card.setField_1(resID);
                } else {
                    card.setField_1(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            }
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I don't know how I can access to item layout and change the alpha.

Comment: Does the code you show work to access the proper `SCard` for the beacon?

Comment: Yes actually this code works. I display a image on the closest beacon item card. More simply i don't know how to access to the alpha of the recyclerview item when i click on a toolbar button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i access to the layout alpha with the object SCard in the adapater :

In the activity i set the alpha

```
card.setField_2(0.5F);
```

In the viewholder i add the setter

```
 public void setItemCardField2(float alpha) {
        swipeLayout.setAlpha(alpha);
    }
```

And the adapter make the job

```
final ShowroomCard card = mItemList.get(position);
viewHolder.setItemCardField2(card.getField_2());
```