# How to set alpha to recyclerview item except clicked one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, opacity, onitemclicklistener

I have a recyclerview with imageview and textview.I populate with it image and text.I have used customadapter for recyclerview.Everything working fine but now i want

1)when i click one image,all other image alpha will be set to 0.5f

Here is my code it alpha itself only

```java
public class CatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatAdapter.HeroViewHolder> {

  Context mCtx;
  List<CatModel> adsList;
  int selectedPosition=-1;

  public CatAdapter(Context mCtx, List<CatModel> heroList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.adsList = heroList;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public HeroViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.cat_recycler_layout, parent, false);

    return new HeroViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HeroViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final CatModel hero = adsList.get(position);

    Glide.with(mCtx)
      .load(hero.getImageurl())
      .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.textView.setText(hero.getName());

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int button01pos = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if (button01pos == 0) {
            holder.cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageView.setAlpha(1f);
            button01pos = 1;
          } else if (button01pos == 1) {
            holder.cross.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imageView.setAlpha(1f);
            button01pos = 0;
          }
        }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return adsList.size();
  }

  class HeroViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView cross;
    CircleImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public HeroViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      cross = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cross);
      textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017052/change-the-alpha-of-recyclerview-item-with-beacon-detection

Comment: You can save your clicked item position in a variable and in `onBindviewHolder` if `clickedPosition !=-1 && clickedPosition!=position` you can set alpha and in `else` you need write `setAlpha(1.0)` to disable alpha for clicked one

Comment: also make sure to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in `onClick()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way.

```
public class CatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatAdapter.HeroViewHolder> {

Context mCtx;
List<CatModel> adsList;
int selectedPosition=-1;
CatModel selectedItem = null;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HeroViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    holder.imageView.setAlpha(selectedItem == null || hero.equals(selectedItem) ? 1f : 0.5f);
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectedItem = hero.equals(selectedItem) ? null : hero;
            ...
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey.It set alpha to all item includes clicked one but i want to set alpha to all item except that i clicked.So how to achieve this ?

Comment: Ok I have edited as you need. Better to change hero.equals(selectedItem)  check  with  hero.getId() == selectedItem.getId() if you have unique ids. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you Sergey your code working like charm but another problem has created i have a cross button top of that image view when i click to image that appear and disappear but now it only disappear not disappear.how to acheive this like imageview here is code>   holder.cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  holder.cross.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: add this row in your onBindViewHolder method.
holder.cross.setVisibility(hero.equals(selectedItem) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE). And remove from Onclick.

Comment: A BIG Thanks to you MR. Sergey Nersesyan.It worked like a magic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

globally 
`selectedItem =-1`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HeroViewHolder holder, int position) {
  if(position == selectedItem)holder.itemView.setAlpha(0.5f)

  holder.itemview.setOnClickListener{
     selectedItem = position
     notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
}
```